# Printing a "Hello World" one-liner in bourne shell without directly using white space char

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, hello-world

I'm currently trying to solve a tricky/silly challenge and i've come to a dead end.

The challenge is basically to form a one-liner /bin/sh compatible command line
which essentially outputs "Hello World" without directly typing White space or Tab characters in the command itself.

for example something like -

```
echo Hello World
```

would be invalid since we used white space twice in the command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! While this is probably a rare case which justifies a language-specific challenge (as it's trivial in many languages but particularly hard in sh), all challenges here need an objective winning criterion. If you get multiple correct answers, which one is the best?

Comment: The most you can do is to use newlines between command and parameters: http://pastebin.com/DU5Gyde7 But this is not POSIX `sh` anymore.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, are you sure about the [tag:bash] tag? The question explicitly asks for “/bin/sh compatible”.

Comment: @manatwork Whoops, good point. Changed to a new [tag:sh].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One which works in `dash`, so I suppose it is `sh` compatible;

```
IFS=@;command=echo@Hello@World;$command
```

Comment: Yup@this@one@works!@great!

Comment: Or simply ``echo${IFS}Hello${IFS}World``

Comment: Yup, $IFS tricks are good.  Here's another way for bash (but not Posix sh): `a=({Hello,world});cat<<<${a[@]}`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, actually `{echo,Hello,world}` is enough in `bash` and `ksh`.

Comment: @manatwork Thats brilliant!